# Making custom Kernel configuration changes with debian-installer in QEMU

Tags: linux, debian, installation, qemu

I am installing Debian10 (armhf) on a virtual machine in QEMU, like this:

1. Download this [netboot/initrd.gz](http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/installer-armhf/current/images/netboot/initrd.gz)
2. Download this [netboot/vmlinuz](http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/installer-armhf/current/images/netboot/vmlinuz)
3. Create an empty disk image with:

   qemu-img create -f qcow2 hda.qcow2 8G
4. Run the `debian-installer` in QEMU with:

   qemu-system-arm -M virt -m 1024 
     -kernel vmlinuz 
     -initrd initrd.gz 
     -drive if=none,file=hda.qcow2,format=qcow2,id=hd 
     -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd 
     -netdev user,id=mynet 
     -device virtio-net-device,netdev=mynet 
     -nographic -no-reboot

The `debian-installer` runs, asks me some basic questions with some text menus, does its job, detects devices and successfully installs a fully functional Debian10 OS.

**THE QUESTION**: How to specify **additional** Kernel Configuration Options, e.g.: [`CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS = y`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/TRACEPOINTS.html) to this installation procedure, so that the `debian-installer` builds the Kernel with these options set ?

*It does not matter if you don't know about the [`CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/TRACEPOINTS.html) kernel config option.  Even some info how to pass additional parameters to the `debian-installer` (kernel builder) in this scenario, would help.*